# use case diagram for basic teacher login

Tags: use-case, diagrams

I am creating a very basic use case diagram to show a teacher login, the login includes a forgot password for obviously if user forgot password and a reset password if they wish to reset password after logging in. My question is that is the below use case diagram create, especially with the include and extend?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is really very basic. Normally, a login would rather be a precondition to other use cases than a use case of it's own. Your question is missing at least one word to make sense of it. I assume you are asking whether it is formally correct. Well, it is not quite.

"Forgot Password" is not an action; you'd rather name it "reset password" (as you did above) because that is something that you can actively and willingly accomplish.
You'd also not name use cases with a verb that is in past tense.

Just delete the "included" use case. Otherwise you end up with a duplicate.

The arrow of the "extend" for the renamed "reset password" must then point to the opposite direction (else it is syntactically correct but makes no sense).

"a reset password if they wish to reset password after logging in"
I'd strongly suggest to offer the "reset password" also at the login screen.
If you'd rather not do that at all, you'd have to attach both use cases directly to the actor (teacher).

[image: suggestion for solution]